# Dynamic programming quiz or comparing two blocks of text

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

***Task definition:***

I try to write my own diff util. I want to implement inline-search.

Means I have two paragraphs of text. I have to constrant strings from first paragraph (*p1*) to strings in second paragraph (*p2*) in such way that sum of common words in constranted strings will be maximal.

And one important point, you can't replace the strings: I mean if you constrant p1[i] to p2[j], than you can't constrant p1[k] to p2[v] if k < i and v < j.

***Little example:***

*Input:*

You have two paragraphs:

```
"Very very very very"         "Very very very"
"bla bla bla"                 "Very very very very very"
"looks like a very dump text" "One more sentence"
"simple text"                 "looks like a peace of ..."
                              "quite simple"
                              "bla bla bla bla"
```

...and matrix where matrix[i][j] = number of common words in string p1[i] and p2[j]

```
3 4 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 3
0 0 0 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
```

*Output:*

You need to constrant them in next way:

```
----------------               "Very very very"
"Very very very very"          "Very very very very very"
"bla bla bla"                  ----------------
----------------               "One more sentence"
"looks like a very dump text"  "looks like a peace of ..."
"simple text"                  "quite simple"
----------------               "bla bla bla bla"
```

Or you can just form the next matrix:

*(indexes of strings which have the constrants)*

`p1Indexes: [0, 2, 3]` 
`p2Indexes: [1, 3 ,4]`

***Question:***

***what is an efficient algorith for this task?***

***[Not obligatory to read] Faced difficulties:***

1. How to pass index-collection to  next iteration: I mean you need to copy all indexes on each iteration
2. If you want to use dynamic programing, you need to store not only a common wors number but also a two indexes collections for each possible iteration.

***Solution:***

```
public void genConditionLCS() {
    int i = -1;
    int j = -1;
    while (true) {
        int[] indexes = nextIndexes(i+1, j+1);
        i = indexes[0];
        j = indexes[1];
        if (i == -1 || j == -1) break;
        firstParagraphIndexes.add(i); 
        secondParagraphIndexes.add(j);
    }
}
private int[] nextIndexes(int i, int j) {
    if ((i > (lcs.length-1)) || (j > (lcs[0].length-1)))
        return new int[] {-1, -1};
    int a = maxBenefit(i + 1, j);
    int b = maxBenefit(i, j + 1);
    int c = maxBenefit(i + 1, j + 1) + lcs[i][j];
    if ((a == 0) && (b == 0) && (c == 0))
        return new int[]{-1, -1};
    else if (a >= b && a >= c)
        return nextIndexes(i+1, j);
    else if (b >= a && b >= c)
        return nextIndexes(i, j+1);
    else //if (c >= a && c >= b)
        return new int[]{i, j};
}

private int maxBenefit(int i, int j) {
    if ((i > lcs.length - 1) || (j > lcs[0].length - 1)) return 0;
    int res = maxBenefit[i][j];
    if (res == -1) {
        int a = maxBenefit(i + 1, j);
        int b = maxBenefit(i, j + 1);
        int c = maxBenefit(i + 1, j + 1) + lcs[i][j];
        res = max(a, b, c);
        maxBenefit[i][j] = res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question. What do you mean by constrant?

Comment: constrant, confront, put them opposite each other

Comment: In your example where did the last string of first paragraph go? 'Simple text'.

Comment: sorry, already corrected

Comment: I have an article series online about a rather naive implementation of a diff algorithm using longest common substring, you can find it here: http://devdirective.com/post/91/creating-a-reusable-though-simple-diff-implementation-in-csharp-part-1

Comment: Thanks, interesting article!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given arrays `a[m]` and `b[n]` and given a cost function: `benefit(i, j)` which calculates the  number of common words between elements `i` and `j`, your problem can be stated as `max_benefit(i, j)` which means that `i` and `j` are aligned/matched and you need to find out the max benefit and alignment of the remaining part, which is: `max(benefit(i + 1, j + 1) + max_benefit(i + 2, j + 2), benefit(i + 2, j + 1) + max_benefit(i + 3, j + 1), benefit(i + 3, j + 1) + max_benefit(i + 4, j + 1), ..., benefit(i + 1, j + 2) + max_benefit(i + 2, j + 3), benefit(i + 1, j + 3) + max_benefit(i + 1, j + 4), ...)`

Now, when you first compute `max_benefit` for any pair of indexes, store the result so that you do not need to reompute it. I. e. check if you have a stored value before computing it; if not, compute it and store the value.

**Re faced difficulties:**

1. You can have the array references available as globals / class members, or you can pass the array references as 2 extra arguments: e. g. `max_benefit(i, j, a, b)` and `benefit(i, j, a, b)`. The arrays won't be copied in most languages.
2. see the main part of this answer, you just recursively compute and store values so that you do not recompute.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But the problem is that how can I store the answer. With big input data length of indexes-collections can growth to hundred or even more, and I can't just store such collection for each possible iteration. See faced difficulties section of my question

Comment: Yes, but if you pass the same collection as argument in the method, it will be changed in all iteration. But you don't need changes from all iterations, you just need changes from optimal iteration. Do you understand me? I can give an example

Comment: @NickoleAbs in my answer I am only computing the `max_benefit` and I am NOT calculating which alignments give the max benefit. I. e. I am determining a property of the answer and not the answer itself. Let me think about answer generation.

Comment: @NickoleAbs consider a function `next_best_i(i, j)` which works similarly to `max_benefit` except that it returns the `i` which gives the `max_benefit` rather than the `max_benefit` itself. similarly create `next_best_j(i, j)`. Now, your first alignment is `next_best_i(0, 0)` and `next_best_j(0, 0)`. Supposing these values are `i1` and `j1`, you can now calculate the next alignment by calling `i2 = next_best_i(i1, j1)` and `j2 = next_best_j(i1, j1)`, and so forth .. makes sense?

Comment: Definitelly yes! ) see edit  section of my question. Am i right?

Comment: @NickoleAbs your edit looks pretty good; does it work? additionally you will need a base case to end the recursion: when `i` or `j` are beyond the end of the array return `0` for `max_benefit`

Comment: Yes, it does. You can see final version of methods in _solution_ section of my question

Comment: Cool, thanks for posting the final version. I already upvoted the question so can't again. PS: now that you understand it most of the conventional terminology uses "cost" rather than "benefit" and accordingly minimizes it. No need to edit your solution; this is just a lingo tip. To use the terminology and the `min` operations you would need to set the matrix values to be negative to make them into costs. Good luck! :)